# Which iphone/android development tools support background notification?

Tags: iphone, android

I am trying to choose an iphone/android tool which supports background notifications. Which ones support this?

At the moment I am considering Corona, Appcelerator, and PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are asking. Are you asking "I want a notification (Alert) sometime in the future"?

If so, in iOS you'll generate UILocalNotification's and schedule them for the future. With Android, there is no such construct, but you can create an AlarmManager Intent that invokes a BroadcastReceiver - in this BroadcastReceiver you will then create the Notification to alert the user at whatever time you desire.

There really aren't any tools, just constructs within the SDK to leverage.

Comment: I mean I want to know whether I can use phonegap, or titanium or something else to receive network notifications from my server for my app